# Getting Google to index externally loaded content (for SEO)

Tags: seo, embed

I'm really struggling to find a way to do this, and I'm hoping someone can come up with some suggestions for more things I can try.

I'm trying to find a way that my site on one domain, say www.mylovelywebsite.com, can embed content from another domain, say www.mysiteprovidingveryinterestingcontent.com, and for that content to get indexed by Google and attributed to the site where it is embedded, ie www.mylovelywebsite.com.

I'm primarily only really interested in Google at this point. So far, I've tried the following approaches with no luck:

**Using an IFrame:**

I've read some sources stating that google does not index IFrame content, and others stating that google will index it but it is attributed to the original source of the content, not to the site where the IFrame is embedded. Either way, this does not solve my problem.

<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://mysiteprovidingveryinterestingcontent/Public/EmbeddedFeed"></script>

**Using <object> tag:**

I think it's the same situation as with the IFrame.

**Using Javascript to document.write the content out:**

I've been looking at [the experiments carried out by this chap](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really),
which show that the content will only be indexed if the javascript statements are in-line in the page being indexed, if they are in an external file then they are not.

Any other suggestions of possible resolutions to this would be very welcome indeed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen iframe content indexed as if it was content of a page but I believe this only happens in some specific situations. In the case I saw, the embedded content was from the same website and it was only ever used within the iframe.

I would suspect in your case the search engines will not pick it up. All you are doing is taking content which they can already find on another website and putting it inside yours. Why would Google want to send people to your page when the original is available. Because of that I don't think they are interested in re-indexing that duplicated content.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. You're right .. so I guess what I'm looking for is a solution whereby the content can be provided to the client website in such a way that the search engine doesn't recognise it is coming from an external source.

Comment: That still may not help. Google is good at determining duplicate or near duplicate content then deciding which copy is the one to show.

Comment: Actually, just to clarify, in this case the content would not be duplicated as it's not included on the source website at all, it is provided solely for the purpose of the client website being able to pick it up and display it.

Comment: You may be ok then. Only way to find out is to test.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved if the content can be accessed via an API on the backend.  The content can simply then be displayed when the page is loaded and Google wont know the content came from somewhere else.

Surprisingly few services offer this integration unfortunately, but it seems like a no-brainer to me.